# MapStateToProps doesn't call componentWillRecieveProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using react-redux to manage states between 3-4 Components. I have 4 Components which act as Pages, whenever one is selected an action calls the reducer to update the selected Tab on the navbar. Simple enough.

I have done everything correctly, it works fine till the point where I can access the state in the mapsStateToProps const in the NavbarComponent but it doesn't re-render the Component. I have tried calling componentWillRecieveProps lifecycle method, but it isn't being called.

### SideNavbarComponent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class SideNavComponent extends Component {

  // Is not called
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(nextProps);
  }

  render() {
    // logs undefined
    console.log(this.props.key);
    return (
      <Nav bsStyle="pills" stacked activeKey={this.props.key}>
        <NavItem disabled eventKey={1}>Home</NavItem>
        <NavItem disabled eventKey={2}>Device</NavItem>
        <NavItem disabled eventKey={3}>Transformations</NavItem>
        <NavItem disabled eventKey={4}>Graphs</NavItem>
      </Nav>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { key } = state.sideNav;

  // I can access via key here
  return { key };
};
```

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SideNavComponent);

### Reducer

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  key: null
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'changed_link':
      return { ...state, key: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

### Action

```
export const linkChange = (key) => {
  return {
    type: 'changed_link',
    payload: key
  };
};
```

---

### Edit

I call the action (linkChange) in each of the 4 Components which act as Pages. One of them is below:

### DeviceComponent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Col, Well } from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
import _ from 'lodash';
import moment from 'moment';

import { linkChange } from '../../actions';

class DeviceComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    device: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/device/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ device: res.data });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });

    this.props.linkChange(2);
  }

  render() {
    const { device } = this.state;
    const battery = _.values(device.battery);
    const generator = _.values(device.generator);
    const Timestamp = moment(device.timestamp).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');

    return (
      <div>
        <Col md={7} sm={12}>
          <h3>Device ID: {device.id} ({device.location})</h3>
          <hr />
          <div style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
            <Link className="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" to="/transform">Transformations</Link>
            <Link className="btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block" to="/graph">Graphs</Link>
          </div>
          <div style={{ marginTop: 70 }}>
            <Link className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" to="/">Home</Link>
          </div>
        </Col>

        <Col md={5} sm={12}>
          <Well>
            <ul>
              <li>ID: {device.id}</li>
              <li>Location: {device.location}</li>
              <li>Timestamp: {Timestamp}</li>
              <li>
                Battery:
                <ul>
                  <li>Temperature: {battery[0]}</li>
                  <li>Current: {battery[1]}</li>
                  <li>Voltage: {battery[2]}</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                Generator:
                <ul>
                  <li>Temperature: {generator[0]}</li>
                  <li>Current: {generator[1]}</li>
                  <li>Voltage: {generator[2]}</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </Well>
        </Col>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { linkChange })(DeviceComponent);
```

Comment: where do you call your action creator `linkChange`

Comment: Edited the question ^

Comment: I think `key` may be a reserved word; could you try renaming it?

Comment: Where are you dispatching the action?

Comment: i'll try renaming the key .... What do you mean dispatching ?? Doesn't the action (linkChange) call the Reducer itself. If in the actions folder I have an index.js its content are: "" export * './Navigation'; ""

Comment: Thanks, renaming key worked. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key` is a reserved word in React - renaming it will resolve the issue